# Python flask-app eventhandler

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently running a few python script to handle some data which I then forward to a html file via the Flask framework.

The data is collected from a specific folder in my project. I would like to add a listener that re-run my scripts if the files are changed inside the specific data folder. I think I can manage the listener but I'm really confused with how I can update the information passed to the html through the flask app.

for example:

```
@app.route("/")
def chart():
    return render_template("chart.html",
    data1=data1, someOtherData=someOtherData)
```

If the listener reacts, I want to update the passed information(`data1`, `someOtherData`). I have tried looking around but cant really get my head around how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the file has changed. You can do it with a loop wich checks the file timestamp every x-seconds.

Or trigger it in the function who changes the data in your folder.

Or you make a loop in Javascript who runs the function.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example from my current project how to render template with new data:

**prog.py**

```
@app.route('/show_all_persons', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def show_all_persons():
    all_persons_query = '''
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        persons
    '''

    persons = sql_conn.query(all_persons_query)
    persons = [dict(p) for p in persons]

    return render_template('childs/show_all_persons.html', persons=persons)
```

**person.html**

```
<table class="table table-light table-hover sort_list">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th style="width: 10em;" scope="col">ID</th>
    <th style="width: 10em;" scope="col">Vorname</th>
    <th id="lastname" scope="col">Nachname</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table-hover">

{% for person in persons %}
<tr class="click" data-href="/show_person/{{ person.person_id }}">
    <td scope="row"><b>#{{ person.person_id }}</b></td>
    <td>{{ person.person_firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.person_lastname }}</td>
</tr>

{% endfor %}

</tbody>
```

Comment: Well, I know how to add the listener to check if the file itself is changed. But I dont understand how to update the information passed via the Flask framework to my html code.

Comment: I don't know what is in your data1 and someOtherData. 

if data1 not an array or list or.. you can put this in your chart.html where you want the data : {% data1 %}

pls read [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

Comment: So if you would update your information in person, the html would update itself using your example? At the moment the data consist of a couple of lists, and some float values.

Comment: The data will be updated when you reload the page. If you want only update the values you can write a javascript file that send a request to a link wich returns a json.

Comment: Okey, but if I only have local information, and don't have the possibility so reload the page since the script will be running on a TV. Could I write a javascript file that automatically reloads the page? Maybe as the last part of the file listener function? Thanks for all the help by the way! My first time using flash and even writing html!

Comment: Flask, not *flash

Comment: with `window.location.reload();`you can reload yor page from a .js. If you want to do it in the last part in the file listener function: `return redirect(url_for('show_all_persons')) # based on my projekt `

Comment: All right! Will try to implement is this weekend, thank you very much for the help! Much appreciated!